# What does c++ static keyword do with braces?

Tags: java, c++, visual-c++

I found this code somewhere, perlin noise generator, I think:

```
static {
    for(int i=0; i<512; i++) perm[i]=p[i & 255];
}
```

What does the static do there? it was spammed in a lot other places as well... The code was practically built with static{} everywhere. I lost the original code somewhere so thats the only thing I have, but it was like that code above: no variable declarations there, which why I dont get it.

Comment: You sure that was C++? You can have static code blocks like that in Java.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin, no, i am not sure... :) should i change tag to C then?

Comment: Was there a `#define static namespace` on the top ?

Comment: @Rookie No, it's definitely not C!

Comment: @ereOn ;-) That wouldn't do. Not for this content.

Comment: I can't compile it in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: I'd like to place a bet that this is Java.

Comment: @ereOn, i dont think so :D i guess i need to find the full code...!

Comment: I would try to run the whole file through the preprocessor (`cl /E filename.cpp`), since probably some preprocessor hackery is involved.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Indeed but I was joking obviously ;) I would also place a bet on Java for this one.

Comment: google results in many mentions of this snippet as jjava, like http://www.gamedev.net/topic/605394-index-wrapping-in-hlsl/

Comment: @ereOn, I did upvote your comment due to its entertaining value, so I figured you were joking :)

Comment: @PlasmaHH, indeed it seems to do that! i just wonder how on earth i got it mixed with C++ ! maybe the code was so short and didnt use any other Java programming styles than the `static` blocks, so i thought it was C++... how embarrassing...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is Java, not C++, which would mean it's a [static initialization block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that it is in fact java code and java static block. Basically, the block that is executed more or less when the static variable would be initialized. (when the class is loaded, but actually I'm not ready to answer questions tagged java).

Answer (score 2):

Documentation of the [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx) keyword at MSDN states it can be used in the following situations:

1. When you declare a variable or function at file scope..
2. When you declare a variable in a function...
3. When you declare a data member in a class declaration
4. When you declare a member function in a class declaration...

Using `static` keyword to declare a [local scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7kfh662%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is not stated here, thus invalid.

If you try to write it in the body of function:

```
void foo(){
    static{
        int i = 0;
    }
}
```

it will lead to ***"error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'"*** because variable declaration is expected. If you replace `static{` with `static;{`, static keyword is ignored so your code becomes compile-able but compiler will still warn you: ***"warning C4091: 'static ' : ignored on left of 'int' when no variable is declared"***.

If you try to write it outside of the body of function, it will lead to ***"error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)"*** because function declaration is expected.